# How to handle ptrdiff_t in SWIG generated Java wrapper?

Tags: java, swig, ptrdiff-t

I have this struct in C:

```
typedef struct THTensor {
  ...
  ptrdiff_t storageOffset;
  ...
} THTensor;
```

However, the SWIG-generated Java code is:

```
public SWIGTYPE_p_ptrdiff_t getStorageOffset() {
    return new SWIGTYPE_p_ptrdiff_t(THJNI.THFloatTensor_storageOffset_get(this.swigCPtr, this), true);
}
```

I'd like that `ptrdiff_t` is converted to `long` in Java, not this `SWIGTYPE_p_ptrdiff_t`, in which I cannot access the actual `long` value.

How can I control this in SWIG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options... But `ptrdiff_t` is unknown to SWIG and to define it just as `long` is not the best idea.
I would do the following: add `%include <stdint.i>` to the interface file and then either add in the interface file:

```
%define ptrdiff_t
intptr_t
%enddef
```

or add in the source code:

```
#ifdef SWIG
  %define ptrdiff_t
  intptr_t
  %enddef
#endif // SWIG
...
typedef struct THTensor {
  ...
  ptrdiff_t storageOffset;
  ...
} THTensor;
```

In such way, the code being wrapped in the interface should have appropriate interpretation of `ptrdiff_t`, not just an opaque pointer.

Comment: My `ptrdiff_t` is mapped to `int` in Java but I'd like to have `long` (64 bit). Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` (`intptr_t`) is mapped to Java `int` on x86 and to Java `long` on x64. You should not hardcode `ptrdiff_t` to Java `long` because if such code is compiled on x86 machine then either a compilation error or just the silent truncation of `long` on the pointer initialization will occur (the implicit error is even worse).

Comment: The problem is I'm running on a x64 computer and SWIG generates Java `int` for `intptr_t`. Interestingly, C types `int`, `long` and `long long` are all correctly mapped to Java `int`, `int` and `long`.

Comment: @tongfei-chen, probably you have some issues in the swig environment or compiler settings. You can build x86 binaries on x64 platform [deliberately] if specify respective compiler options. Also, you should check whether x64 or x86 swig build is used. In the end, the issue of mapping `intptr_t` to Java `int` relates to YOUR build environment and/or compiler settings, not to the swig or the listed above header file.